# RabbitMQ EventingBasicConsumer no responding after some time

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitClient as Queue reader singleton in my .NET Core application (publishing to queue goes through other application). And I'm facing the problem when after some time my application stops reading from queue. I hosted my service on AKS. Below is my code. It's running fine for 2 to 5 minutes and processing messages but it is stopping and not reading messages after that. When I stop receiving messages, my consumer stay connected to the RabbitMQ server. My RabbitMQ server version is 3.8.4

```
enter code here
```

```
 consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    log.InfoFormat("[ {0} ] New Message received", customerid);

                    log.Warn("to troubleshoot deployemnt issue");

                    string assetid = null;

                    try
                    {


                            List<AlarmLog> lia = ds.calculateAlarm(assetid, assettype, customerid, timest);
                            log.Debug($"Total alarms generated for {assetid} is {lia.Count}");


                            if (lia.Count > 0)
                            {
                                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: Aura.Config.Config.Instance.NotificationExchange,
                                        routingKey: "",
                                        basicProperties: null,
                                        body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lia)));
                            }


                        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);

                    }
                    catch(Exception overall)
                    {
                        log.Error($"error in consumer.Received: assetid: {assetid}. " + overall.ToString());
                        channel.BasicReject(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, requeue: false);
                    }

                    watch.Stop();
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    log.Debug("[ " + customerid + " ]" + "Completed " + ea.DeliveryTag + " of activities in " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                };
```

Comment: Start by having a look for clues in the RabbitMQ server logs in AKS.

Comment: Could you please add code, how connection manage in your code?